# Error: 'Bad file descriptor'

Tags: python

I don't understand why I keep getting the following error message when I run my code:

```
with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile:
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

This is my code:

```
import collections

classChoice = int(input("Which class do you want to order? "))
if classChoice == 1:
    open ("Class 1.txt")
elif classChoice == 2:
    open ("Class 2.txt")
else:
    open ("Class 3.txt")

scores = {}
def alphabetical():
    with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile: 
        for line in resultfile:
            name, score = lines.split(":")
            scores.setdefault(name, collections.deque(maxlen=3)).append(int(score))

    for name in sorted(scores):
        m = max(scores[name])
        print('{name}: {m}'.format(name=name, m=m))

def highestScore():
    with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile:
        for line in resultfile:
            name, score = line.split(":")
            scores.setdefault(name, collections.deque(maxlen=3)).append(int(score))

    for name in sorted(scores, key=lambda name: max(scores[name]), reverse=True):
        m = max(scores[name])
        print('{name}: {m}'.format(name=name, m=m))

def averageScore():
    with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile:
        d = {}
        for line in resultfile:
            column = line.split(":")
            names = column[0]
            scores = int(column[1].strip())
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
        averages=[]

        for names, v in d.items():
            average = (sum(v[-3:])/len(v[-3:]))
            averages.append((names, average))
        for names, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
            print(names, average)

orderChoice = (input("How do you want to order the data? "))
if orderChoice == "alphabetically":
                  alphabetical()
elif orderChoice == "with highest score for the tests, highest to lowest":
                  highestScore()
else:
                  averageScore()
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Because you're trying to open a number, `if classChoice == 1: open ("Class 1.txt")` doesn't do what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

open expects a string and you give it an int. I think what you're trying to do is

```
classChoice = int(input("Which class do you want to order? "))
if classChoice == 1:
    classChoice = "Class 1.txt"
elif classChoice == 2:
    classChoice = "Class 2.txt"
else:
    classChoice = "Class 3.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it says that:

Comment: name, score = lines.split(":")
NameError: global name 'lines' is not defined

Comment: And also: name, score = lines.split(":")
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This is when I am trying to use the 'alphabetical' function, when I try to use the 'highestScore' function, it tells me this: scores.setdefault(name, collections.deque(maxlen=3)).append(int(score))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 out of 10.\n'                                Also, when I try to use the 'averageScore' function, this happens: scores = int(column[1].strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 out of 10.'

Comment: Yes i know how to fix this, but really all the mistakes you made are very basic and the error messages you get are very explicit : using a variable that doesn't exist, calling the split method on something that don't have it, giving the int function a string it can't handle  (it even tells you what the string is, just look at the file you're opening, and you'll see the problem). Sorry if I seems rude, but it looks like what you need is a tutorial more than someone that give you all the answers.

Comment: I'm not great at code unfortunately. In this instance I would really appreciate answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
classChoice = int(input("Which class do you want to order? "))
if classChoice == 1:
    open ("Class 1.txt")
elif classChoice == 2:
    open ("Class 2.txt")
else:
    open ("Class 3.txt")
```

`open ("Class <num>.txt")` will do nothing after opened the file.

However, here:

```
with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile:
```

You're trying to open `classChoice`. What is it? Let me guess, it's either `1`, `2`, or `3`.

- When you're trying to open a number, you're trying to open a *file descriptor*.
- When you opened a file, Python also created a *file descriptor* for it...you don't really need understand what it is now.

I'd suggest change your code to:

```
classChoice = int(input("Which class do you want to order? "))
if classChoice == 1:
    filename = "Class 1.txt"
elif classChoice == 2:
    filename = "Class 2.txt"
else:
    filename = "Class 3.txt"
```

And change every below lines:

```
with open(classChoice, 'r+') as resultfile:
```

to:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as resultfile:
```